# How can I limit 'stream_loop -1' dynamically when using 'filter_complex'?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I have a 2 inputs, a video file and an audio file.

The video input should be a background video, meaning it should repeat infinitely (both audio and video) and it's audio component volume should be reduced to 15%.

Also, I want the background video component to be filtered (I used `hue` filter for the example).

The second input should be mixed with 1's input audio (reduced to 15% volume level), and determinate the total output video length.

I tried this:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i vid.mp4 -i aud.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]volume=0.15[a0]; \
 [1:a][a0]amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest:dropout_transition=0[audio]; \ 
 [0:v]hue=h=90[video]" -map "[audio]" -map "[video]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest out.mp4
```

But it doesn't work (`vid.mp4` is repeating endlessly without audio).

While, this:

```
'ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i vid.mp4 -i aud.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]volume=0.15[a0];[a0][1:a]amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest:dropout_transition=0[audio];" \
-map 0:v -map "[audio]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest out.mp4'
```

works (But I need to `filter_complex` the video too).

How can I achieve it? Is this a bug?

Comment: Which version ?

Comment: @Gyan ffmpeg version N-109937-g05438db024-20230228

Comment: Updated to latest, (N-110808-g62d4110a64-20230528) still the same.

Comment: @Gyan Is there a workaround to achieve the same result in a (working) different way?

Comment: See the formulation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62372712/165358).

Comment: @harrymc Didn't work, same error

Comment: Strange, these kind of formulations have worked for many people. Why not for you?

Comment: @harrymc I am using filer_complex. See my second example which does work, but it's without filter

Comment: See if [this bug report](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6121) applies to your case, and if the movie filter can replace stream_loop.

Comment: @harrymc It has nothing to do with my question. In my case the audio loops ***infinitely*** without stopping, and using -shortest doesn't help, There, It only played once and doesn't repeat like he wants ("I want to overlay a spinner on top of a video. When I use the -stream_loop option (either with -1 or an arbitrary number of repetitions), the input file is not looped, just played once") and this that's his problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [documented bug](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9487): `-shortest` will not work when using `-filter_complex` both with audio and video filters.

That said, the easiest option you have is to add `-t` before the input and insert the length of your audio, while at the same time setting `-stream_loop` to something else than infinite. Let's suppose your audio is 10 minutes, or 600 seconds, you would use `-t 600` BEFORE the input file:

```
ffmpeg -t 600 -stream_loop 1000 -i vid.mp4 -i aud.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]hue=h=90[video]; \
 [0:a]volume=0.15[a0]; \
 [1:a][a0]amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest:dropout_transition=0[audio]" -map "[audio]" -map "[video]" -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

Comment: That's indeed what I did eventually.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to loop a background video indefinitely and combine its audio (at a reduced volume) with another audio file. You want to apply a filter to the video stream and also want the length of the output to be determined by the second audio file. It seems the current command is unable to apply the video filter and loop the video simultaneously.

Try the following command:

```bash
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i vid.mp4 -i aud.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]hue=h=90,loop=0:32767:0,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[v];[0:a]volume=0.15[a0];[1:a][a0]amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest[a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -shortest out.mp4
```

In this command, I added the loop filter directly in the filter complex to loop the video. The `setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB` filter makes sure that the timestamps are set correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what you expect to happen vs what actually happens?

Comment: Same, endless loop

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i vid.mp4 -i aud.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]hue=h=90,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[filtered_video]; \
[0:a]volume=0.15[a0]; \
[filtered_video][a0]concat=n=1:v=1:a=1[output_video][output_audio]" \
-map "[output_video]" -map "[output_audio]" -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

give a try to concat if it will help so the total duration will be determined by the audio input.